# Syntax error, unrecognized expression in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-escape-characters

I have to select a `div` element `id` with `escape characters`,

**HTML**

```
<div id="abc/def"></div>
```

Tried these,

```
$("#abc/def").find('h4').attr('data-val', "test")  //didn't work

$("id=[abc/def]").find('h4').attr('data-val', "test")  //didn't work

$("#"+escapeSelector("abc/def")).find('h4').attr('data-val',"Test")   //didn't work

function escapeSelector(s) {
    return s.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

**Error:**

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #abc/def
```

Where should i make the change to make this work?

Comment: As an option, you may try `jQuery("div[id^=abc]")` OR `jQuery("#abc\\/def")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#abc\\/def").text("test")  //did work :)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtpkkyw0/

There is really good info on the jquery site as well. Leaving here as a reference, hope it helps someone:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yeah, you need to escape a few chars in jquery selector. You need this also for `[ ]`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to escape anything with the [Attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) :

```
$('[id="abc/def"]')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86uohuny/